# Ruby on Rails: How to link/route from one view/page to another view/page with a different controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, routes, view

I have a view template within the following file in my Rails application:

```
app/views/static_pages/mission.html.erb
```

I want to link to that page from a view template in a different folder (corresponding to a different page in the app):

```
app/views/home/home.html.erb
```

I don't know what to write in my `mission` method in the `StaticPagesController`. I'm also a newbie at Rails. I also don't know how to write the route for it and I suspect I may need to write a get 'something' in my *routes.rb* file.

Can anybody help with this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What you are asking can be accomplished in this way:

In your *routes.rb*:

```
get "/path/to/your/mission/page", to: "static_pages#mission", as: "mission"
```

Then in your *static_pages_controller.rb*:

```
class StaticPagesController < ApplicationController

  # You can leave the mission method blank, it will render
  # the corresponding static_pages/mission.html.erb by default

  def mission
  end

end
```

This should set up the static page, so that when you visit: `localhost:3000/path/to/your/mission/page`, you should be able to see the mission.html.erb page rendered.

To link to the mission page from any other template, you can simply point a link to it, like so:

```
<%= link_to "Mission Page", mission_path %>
```

Or, since it's a static page, you can just hardcode the path into the markup:

```
<a href="/path/to/your/mission/page">Mission Page</a>
```

Since you're new to Rails (welcome to the world of Rails btw :D), I hope you find these really great resources useful:

- [Official Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/index.html)
- [Rails For Zombies](https://www.codeschool.com/courses/rails-for-zombies-redux)
- [Railscasts by Ryan Bates](http://railscasts.com/)

Hope this was helpful!

Comment: This helped me understand what I was looking for in my application! As an added follow up question, would you know how to use .less files in Rails? Do I put them in the same folder as my stylesheets? How do i call them in application view?